# How to add condition middle of append

Tags: jquery, html, append

I have this jquery code where append stuff to one div:

```
$("#destinations ul").append('<li>' +
            '<h2>' +  destination[i].city + '</h2>' +
            '<p>' + destination[i].desc + 'p>' + 
            '<div class="meta">' +
            '<span class=meta-date>Added ' + destination[i].added_date + '</span>' +
            '<span class="meta-comments"><a href="' + destination[i].url + '#reply">' + destination[i].comment_amount + ' comments</a></div>' +
            '</div></li>');
```

This works perfectly. Except in cases if I don't have any comments or date. Then i see div with text 'Added' without date. So I would like to put meta-date and meta-comments lines as conditionals. Like:

```
   if (added_date) {
 '<span class=meta-date>Added ' + destination[i].added_date + '</span>' +
}
```

But if i add that in my first code, it gives me error. What way I could do this? How should I modify my code? This is simple but I missing something now, but no clue what. Brain freeze :)

Comment: post ur code in jsfiddle if possible..

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
var str = '<li><h2>'+destination[i].city+'</h2><p>'+destination[i].desc+'p>'+ 
           '<div class="meta">';
if (added_date) {
   str += '<span class="meta-date">Added '+destination[i].added_date+'</span>';
}
str += '<span class="meta-comments"><a href="'+destination[i].url+'#reply">'+
         destination[i].comment_amount+' comments</a></span>' +
        '</div></li>';
$("#destinations ul").append(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#destinations ul").append('<li>' +
        '<h2>' +  destination[i].city + '</h2>' +
        '<p>' + destination[i].desc + 'p>' + 
        '<div class="meta">' +
        (added_date)?'<span class=meta-date>Added ' + destination[i].added_date + '</span>' : '') +
        '<span class="meta-comments"><a href="' + destination[i].url + '#reply">' + destination[i].comment_amount + ' comments</a></div>' +
        '</div></li>');
```

you can change the '' empty string if needed

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will surely works...

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#destination ul').append(function(n){
       var appendstr = '<li><h2>'+destination[i].city+'</h2><p>'+destination[i].desc+'p>'+ 
       '<div class="meta">';
        if (date) {
            appendstr += '<span class="meta-date">Added '+destination[i].added_date+'</span>';
        }
        appendstr += '<span class="meta-comments"><a href="'+destination[i].url+'#reply">'+
     destination[i].comment_amount+' comments</a></span>' +
    '</div></li>';
    return appendstr;
        });
  });
```